# C#... Not all code paths return a value

Tags: c#, accessor

I am trying to create a Collection with properties and their respective accessors.

Here is my code:

```
class SongCollection : List<Song>
{
    private string playedCount;
    private int totalLength;

    public string PlayedCount
    {
        get
        {
            foreach (Song s in this)
            {
                if (s.TimesPlayed > 0)
                {
                    return s.ToString();
                }
            }
        }
    }


    public int TotalLength
    {
        get
        {
            foreach (Song s in this)
            {
                int total = 0;
                total += s.LengthInSeconds;
            }
            return total;
        }
    }
}
```

I'm receiving the error at the "get" point. It tells me that not all code paths return a value... What exactly does this mean, and what am I missing?

Comment: I think you need to review your design. Specifically your `PlayedCount` property.

Comment: you forgot to return outside of if statement

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Firstly, the reason you're getting that message is that if `this` is empty, then the code within the `foreach` block (which is where the required `return` statement is) would never be executed.

However, your `TotalLength()` function would always return the length of the first `Song`, as you're declaring your variable, setting its value, then returning it within the `foreach` block. Instead, you'd need to do something like this:

```
int totalLength = 0;

foreach(Song s in this)
{
    total += s.LengthInSeconds;
}

return totalLength;
```

Your `PlayedCount` function suffers from similar issues (if the collection is empty or contains no elements whose `TimesPlayed` property is greater than 0, then there would be no way for it to return a value), so judging by your comment you could write it this way:

```
public int PlayedCount()
{
    int total = 0;

    foreach(Song s in this)
    {
        if (s.TimesPlayed > 0)
        {
            total++;
        }
    }

    return total;
}
```

Comment: Also, the `if` might never evaluate to true (in `PlayedCount`).

Comment: @AnthonyPegram Thanks, I didn't even look at the first function.

Comment: I'm creating these accessors so that when I instatiate and populate the List<> in my main() function, I can use them to access them. Can I populate the list in the class itself?

Comment: @iggy2012 What is the `PlayedCount` function supposed to *do*?

Comment: Once populated in the main() it's supposed to get the number of songs that have been played at least once. I have a play method that increments the TimesPlayed property from the Song class.

Answer (score 0):

It means just as it says, not all code paths return a value.

In this case, if your list is empty, then it cannot call return.  In a foreach, there must be at least one item for the code to execute.  Now, maybe you know that the list will always contain a value, but the compiler can't know that

Answer (score 0):

What would your method return if this did not evaluate?

```
 if (s.TimesPlayed > 0)
                {
                    return s.ToString();
                }
```

try using an else to return an empty string or something

Answer (score 0):

The fact that 'this' could have no songs- in that case the loops will not execute at all and there is no implicit return value in C#.

Furthermore, your getters don't really make sense unless you only ever had one song in the collection.  You need something more like this:

```
public int TotalLength()
{
    get
    {
        int total = 0;
        foreach (Song s in this)
        {
            total += s.LengthInSeconds;
        }
        return total;    
    }
}
```

Finally, without knowing how you keep track of TimesPlayed for each individual song, I wouldn't know how to implement that getter, but I am sure you can figure it out with this much.